# Keras implementation issue unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Tags: machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

The Keras implementation of MNIST CNN shown [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py) shows the following error:

```
TypeError: softmax() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

I spent a long time trying to fix it but nothing works. I am running TensorFlow 1.1.0 and Keras 2.1.6. Thank you for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use this command to update the version of TensorFlow.

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow      # for Python 2.7
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow     # for Python 3.n
```

Answer (score 1):

Your TensorFlow version is too old, you need to upgrade, preferrably to the latest version (currently 1.8).